# What happens to a published app that have android min version upgraded

Tags: android, google-play, android-version

Consider the following scenario,

I have a published app targeting min android version 16, and I upgrade this version to 21.

What happen to users that have the app installed in android versions below 21?

Users still would be able to use the app, but do not receive updates, or the users got their app uninstalled?

Comment: they still can use the old app.. no update for them.. only API 21 above receive update

Comment: But if they uninstall the app, they will not be able to install it again, right?

Comment: yups..unless they have old app .apk file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices not compatible with your current release will stay on the latest compatible release, until the user uninstalls your app. After that, it is not possible to install the app on that device again, aside from sideloading it.

Noteworthy is that if you later provide an apk compatible with API 16, old installations can be updated again.

This mechanism can also be used to e.g. serve different apks to tablets and phones.